# Is patent US 5881419 A still active?

Tags: patent-lifetime

In reference to the patent: [US5881419](https://patents.google.com/patent/US5881419A/en)

Is this patent still active?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you check the status of a US patent or application. Go to the [US Public Pair](https://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) site. Get past the CAPTCHA and then enter the document's number to search. In this case it is a patent number so select that option and enter 5881419. Pair is very picky about formats. From the initial page in the upper right part of the window you can find the current status. In this case for US5881419, the current status is: "Patent Expired Due to NonPayment of Maintenance Fees Under 37 CFR 1.362" with a status date of 04-16-2003. This means the patent was expired due to not paying required fees. I think it is theoretically possible to reinstate the patent and pay back fees if you can convince the patent office the lack of payment wasn't intentional. However even if the owner of the patent wanted to do that, the patent would have naturally expired on 12-23-2017 which at the time of this answer is exactly 1 month away. This is determined by adding 20 years to the date listed in Pair as the "Filing or 371 (c) Date". While there is a possibility of an extention, it would be mentioned in Pair if one existed. Thus, for all practical purposes, **this patent is expired**.